# React event handlers don't work in <object> while loading PDF

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling

I'm pretty new with React and I don't know this piece of code doesn't work.

I'd like to handle both `onError` and `onLoadedMetadata` when loading a pdf file from a URL. (The URL in the example is wrong on purpose)

```js
class MyPDF extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      errorMsg: null
    };
    this.onDocumentErrorLoad = this.onDocumentErrorLoad.bind(this);
  }

  setErrorMsg(msg) {
    this.setState({
      errorMsg: msg
    });
  }

  onDocumentErrorLoad(event) {
    console.log("fine1");
    this.setErrorMsg("Error" + event);
  }

  handleMetadata = (event) => {
    console.log("fine2");
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <object
        height="500"
        data={"httpssss://gooogle.come"}
        type="application/pdf"
        onError={this.onDocumentErrorLoad}
        onLoadedData={() => console.log("try")}
        onLoadedMetadata={this.handleMetadata}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

None of these callbacks work, but if I put a simple `{console.log("try")}` as callback then it works.

Can someone tell me why and how to solve this? I can't figure it out

Comment: Hi what is object here ? is it a user-defined component ( which is supposed to be starting with capital letter though)?

Comment: @Anu It's the classic HTML [object](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_object.asp)

Comment: Your code seems to be written correct. I see, you used various types of functions, probably wanted to understand what's going on wrong (traditional and arrow). I'd say, you know React uses synthetic events to support most browsers native events, so maybe you used some events which are not supported in your react version so far, or those events were attached to your `object` element correctly, but their handlers were not called by reason of those events not fired or emitted at all for some reason. But, why in this case () => console.log('try') was called, I didn't understand, it's very odd.